# TSQL remap big number to smaller, but keep Identity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to load a huge number into `Field1 INT` which can hold only `max=2,147,483,647`, according to it I can't change DDL, so tried to find adhoc solution to cut out single digit from the middle of this number and then add check for uniqueness.
This numbers are in the format like: `29000001234`, so I mean to keep this format with zeros in the middle to easy recognizing.  I don't want to introduce any new columns/tables into this task, as limited in freedom there, this is 3rd party schema.

Can anybody suggest better solution, how to remap/keep all numbers under that limit; this is my draft:

```
DECLARE @fl FLOAT = 29000001234
DECLARE @I  INT

SELECT  @i = (SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(@fl AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(18)),1,4) +  
          SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(@fl AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(18)),7,LEN(CAST(CAST(@fl AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(18))))  )
select @i;
```

Answer (score 1):

But if you really want to remove the middle digits, here's another approach:

```
DECLARE @fl FLOAT = 29000001234
DECLARE @I  INT

DECLARE @StringFloat as varchar(80)
SET @StringFloat = CONVERT(varchar(80), CAST(@fl AS bigint))
SET @I = CAST( CONCAT(LEFT( @StringFloat, 4 ), RIGHT( @StringFloat, 5 )) as int )

SELECT @i;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think arithmetic operations should be less expensive than string operations, so you should use them instead:

```
DECLARE @fl FLOAT = 29000001234 
DECLARE @flBig BIGINT = @fl
DECLARE @i  INT

SET @i = (@flBig / 1000000000) * 10000000 + (@flBig % 100000000)
select @i;  --> 290001234
```

Provided example assumes the first part of the number will have a maximum of two digits (i.e. `29` in your case) and that you want to allow larger number in the left part (up to `999999`).

**NOTE:** parentheses are redundant, as division and multiplication have the same priority and modulo operator has higher precedence over addition. I have used them just to highlight the parts of the computation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without any arithmetic overflow, or with out losing your original data.
If you have a limitation in columns of your destination table or query, use multiple rows:

```
declare @c bigint = 29000001234;
declare @s bigint = 1000000000;    -- Separator value

;with cte(partNo, partValue) as (
    select 1, @c % @s
    union all
    select partNo + 1, (@c / power(@s, partNo)) % @s
    from cte
    where (@c / power(@s, partNo)) > 0
)
select partValue
from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a strange situation, not sure why you need to go to all the trouble of converting a big number to a string and then randomly remove a digit. Some more information about why or what the real goal is would be helpful.

That said, maybe it would be easier to just subtract a constant amount from these values? e.g.:

```
DECLARE @fl FLOAT = 29000001234
DECLARE @I INT
DECLARE @OFFSET BIGINT = 29000000000
SET @I = CAST(@fl AS BIGINT)-@OFFSET
SELECT @I
```

Which gives you an `INT` of `1234` as the result using your example.

Comment: Tx all, Alexei solution is best for me,  here is what  I have: 1.  I have like 10K+ rows,  2.  This field should be Unique,   3. This field should fit INT (less 2147483647).   4. I don't have any control to change any DDL in destination      6. Ideally I would like to maintain pattern of this IDs for tracking/research

Comment: Tx Rocky, it works too, I just need keep that pattern, i.e. keep same first and last 3-4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

The following creation drops increasingly wide blocks of digits from the original *third party value* and returns the results that fit in an `INT`. The results could be outer joined with the existing data to find a suitable new value.

```
declare @ThirdPartyValue as BigInt = 29000001234;
declare @MaxInt as BigInt = 2147483647;

declare @TPV as VarChar(19) = Cast( @ThirdPartyValue as VarChar(19) );
declare @TPVLen as Int = Len( @TPV );

with
  -- 0 through 9.
  Digits as (
    select Digit from ( values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9) ) as Digits( Digit ) ),
  -- 0 through   @TPVLen .
  Positions as (
    select Ten_1.Digit * 10 + Ten_0.Digit as Number
      from Digits as Ten_0 cross join Digits as Ten_1
      where Ten_1.Digit * 10 + Ten_0.Digit <= @TPVLen ),
  -- 1 through   @TPVLen - 1 .
  Widths as (
    select Number
      from Positions
      where 0 < Number and Number < @TPVLen ),
  -- Try dropping   Width   digits at   Position   from   @TPV .
  AlteredTPVs as (
    select P.Number as Position, W.Number as Width,
      Stuff( @TPV, P.Number, W.Number, '' ) as AlteredTPV
      from Positions as P cross join Widths as W
      where P.Number + W.Number <= @TPVLen )
  -- See which results fit in an   Int .
  select Position, Width, AlteredTPV, Cast( AlteredTPV as BigInt ) as AlteredTPVBigInt
    from AlteredTPVs
    where Cast( AlteredTPV as BigInt ) <= @MaxInt -- Comment out this line to see all results.
    order by Width, Position
```

It could be more clever about returning only distinct new values.

This general idea could be used to hunt down blocks of zeroes or other suitable patterns to arrive at a set of values to be tested against the existing data.