# Sql Nested temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if it is possible to create a temporary table within another temporary table, then run a query off the outer nested table.

I have a query on 2 joined tables that produce a list of sales orders assigning stock on more than one warehouse at a time. (first temp table). I now need to use this list as a temp table to query back into one of the original raw data tables to collect data only of the listed sales orders.

Comment: You can't create nested tables. Why not use two tables with a foreign key? What problem are you trying to solve? BTW SSMS is just the IDE, not SQL Server.

Comment: I know ssms is the ide. I created the post on my app and it would not let me select the sql server tag.

Comment: The second table uses data from the first.

Comment: It is common to use multiple CTEs in a single `WITH`. The various temporary result sets can be referenced multiple times. [Examples](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look at your link.

Comment: Question doesn't make sense... Please read up on relational databases. Nested tables are not a thing. You can certainly USE DATA from two tables, but 'nesting' the tables is not a thing that makes any sense

Comment: @StevendeBeer just use two different tables with a foreign key. You don't need to "nest" anything

Comment: Please note I am not creating tables, nor foreign keys. This is for a single query. I do not have permission for creation, but is expected to solve this issue. I need an on-the-fly query to return the result, that is why I need to nest. Read my other comments.

Comment: You are clearly using the term 'Nested' in the wrong way... Are you asking how to join two temporary tables? If so - the same way you join normal tables. If not - please show us sample table schemas and expected results so we can tell what the hell you are talking about

Comment: I will have an example tomorrow. It is very hard to illistrate what I mean sorry. I am refering to nesting, not joins.

Comment: Are you asking about something like `select ... from ( select ... from Foo... ) as Bar`? That would be using a _derived table_. Using <your-favorite-search-engine> to search for `t sql derived table` should get you documentation and examples.

Comment: HABO this is just about the same as creating single temp table. I need more layers to get the detail I require. If I could create an example niw I would, but it would have to wait until morning. (GMT+2)

Comment: I have edited my question for more clarity until I can add a proper example.

Comment: @HABO as per your link, can I reference the first CTE in the second CTE? If so, I might be able to get the query to work.

Comment: Yes, you can mix and match CTEs within a single `WITH`. You might create `A` and `B`, then `C` from `B` and some other tables, `D` from `A` and `C`, ... . For debugging, you can `SELECT` from any of the CTEs (or combination thereof) at the end of the `WITH`. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41517700/92546) goofy answer is a bad example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with @HABO's link provided in one of his comments, I have solved the issue. below is my resolution

```
WITH salesorderwhlist 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT sordetail.salesorder, 
                         sordetail.mwarehouse AS Warehouse 
         FROM   sordetail 
                INNER JOIN sormaster 
                        ON sordetail.salesorder = sormaster.salesorder 
         WHERE  ( sordetail.linetype NOT IN ( '4', '5', '6', '7' ) ) 
                AND ( sordetail.mshipqty <> 0 ) 
                AND ( sormaster.orderstatus NOT IN ( '8', '9', 'S', '\', '*' ) ) 
        ), 
     filteredlist 
     AS (SELECT salesorder, 
                Count(salesorder) AS WhCount 
         FROM   salesorderwhlist AS SOWL 
         GROUP  BY salesorder 
         HAVING Count(salesorder) > 1) 
SELECT sordetail.* 
FROM   sordetail 
       RIGHT JOIN filteredlist 
               ON sordetail.salesorder = filteredlist.salesorder
```

Thanks HABO for your input.